# Exact match of a string variable in another string in python

Tags: python

A simple question.

```
string = "My name is Ramesh and I am cool. You are Ram ?"
sub = "Ram"
```

I need a python method to return if sub is found in string.
But with a condition that "Ramesh" should not be considered but only "Ram" should get return -> Exact match of my sub in string.

Comment: Hey Bro, Here you go, hope this helps

```
 # Declares
 string = "My name is Ramesh and I am cool. You are Ram ?"
 sub = "Ram"

 # Check String For SUb String
 result = sub in string

 # Condition Check
 if result:

    # find starting position
    start_position = string.index(sub)

    # get stringlength
    length = len(sub)

    # return string
    output = string[start_position:len]
```